# How to use ternary operator using _.map in angularjs

Tags: javascript, lodash

I need to return true or false based on some condition, I am not getting the cleaner code to do this:

I need to hide or show some elements on UI based on this condition which should return true or false:

```
scope.isDataEnabled =function(options){ //Here if supppose a comes,
                           // then i need to send true, otherwise false
    if(!$rootScope.currentProduct.id ==
        ProductConstants.BB_PRODUCT_ID){
            return true;
        }
   else{
       _.map( $rootScope.currentUser.permissions, permissionObj =>{
           // permissions is an Array
           return (permissionObj.module == "DATA" &&
              permissionObj.values == "b" && options=="a") //need to send true 
                                           //if this condition satisfies
       });
    }
    return false; //after returning true,
                  //it comes to this line and sets to false
}
```

Please help me guide, what i should use, to achieve it. I was thinking of using ternary operator, but not getting how to use it inside map.

Comment: `!$rootScope.currentProduct.id ==  ProductConstants.BB_PRODUCT_ID` should be `$rootScope.currentProduct.id !==  ProductConstants.BB_PRODUCT_ID` I suppose. Try that first

Comment: okay, i corrected it.. But still my problem remains the same. After going in else block for other values it sets false, but for value 'a' after setting to true, it sets false again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifying your code to a minimal test scenario that can be manipulated (and just use plain old ES20xx) may help. Something like:

```js
let $rootScope = {
  currentProduct: {
    id: `x`
  },
  currentUser: {
    permissions: [{
      module: `BB_DATASET`,
      values: `b`
    }, {
      module: `some`,
      values: `a`
    }]
  }
};
const ProductConstants = {
  BB_PRODUCT_ID: `y`
}

console.log(testMe(`a`)); // true (currentProduct.id not BB_PRODUCT_ID)

ProductConstants.BB_PRODUCT_ID = `x`;
console.log(testMe(`a`)); // true (module && values && options)

$rootScope.currentUser.permissions[0].module = `AA_DATASET`;
console.log(testMe(`a`)); // false (module not BB_DATASET)

$rootScope.currentUser.permissions[0].module = `BB_DATASET`;
console.log(testMe(`b`)); // false (options not `a`)

$rootScope.currentUser.permissions[0].values = `c`;
console.log(testMe(`a`)); // false (values not `b`)

function testMe(options) {
  if ($rootScope.currentProduct.id !== ProductConstants.BB_PRODUCT_ID) {
    return true;
  }
  const found = $rootScope.currentUser.permissions.find( v =>
    v.module === `BB_DATASET` &&
    v.values === `b` &&
    options == `a`);
  return found ? true : false;

}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the return inside of the map function will not return the value to the outer function, you are only returning the result to the map function itself. The result of the map function is never being returned.

Also, I think you might want to use `_.some` instead of map. `map` is used for transforming data, while `some` is used to check if something matches a condition.

```
return _.some($rootScope.currentUser.permissions, permissionObj => {
    return (permissionObj.module == "BB_DATASET"
        && permissionObj.values == "b" 
        && options=="a")
});
```

This will check if *any* of the permissions match the given condition. Alternatively you can use `_.all` if you want everything to match the condition.